# Is it possible to have a Heroku app that is just a python console?

Tags: python, heroku

I have been writing a pretty simple python quizz system (called game.py) and I am working to deploy it on heroku. The app functions exclusively within the confines of a python console, with no interface of any kind but that provided by a terminal.

As such, I would like to be able to have the application on Heroku simply be akin to what you obtain with a one-off dyno, available on the dashboard (or in a terminal with the CLI) with:

```
heroku run python game.py
```

The application works perfectly well in it's deployed form (exclusively from the Heroku git) and locally, but in order for the app to be available to a larger public, I would need to have such a console appear on the "https://[appname].herokuapp.com/" URL that you are given on deployment of the app.

Naively, I would think this to be unspeakably simple to pull off, but I have yet to find a way to do it.

The only reasonable thing I have found would have been to create a Procfile, but lacking any documentation on the commands available, I only have been able to try variations of:

```
web: run python game.py
```

Which doesn't create a web console. And:

```
web: bash
```

Which simply crash with error code h10, with no other information given.

Any help, any suggestion, any workaround you can think of would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Well, I think the major issue is that Python doesn't run in the browser just like that.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't, however, Heroku is more than capable of creating a console-like interface in the browser. I just want to make this behavior the "default" so to speak.